# Custom http headers for all actions from $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have troubles finding in the docs, something that allows me to define my custom http headers for all the actions of a specific $resource, Did you know how to do this?

This is what I want to avoid

```
return $resource(main.dev + '/api/:entity/:action', '', {
    SaveUser: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            entity: 'users',
            action: 'register'
        },
        headers: {
            api_key: main.api_key //same header 
        }
    },
    get:{
        headers: {
            api_key: main.api_key //same header 
        }  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a httpinterceptor like so:

```
define(['./app'], function (app) {
  'use strict';
  return app.factory('requestInterceptor', ['$log', function ($log) {
    var requestInterceptor = {
      request: function (config) {
        $log.debug(config);

        //YOUR CODE HERE
        //if config.url starts with /api
        //config.headers.push token

        return config;
      }
    };
    return requestInterceptor;
  }]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');
  }]);
});
```

When `config.url` starts with api you insert your headers into `config.headers`.